# Count instances of a field in ElasticSearch index

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm curious about the best approach to count the instances of a particular field, across all documents, in a given ElasticSearch index.

For example, if I've got the following documents in index `goober`:

```
{
    '_id':'foo',
    'field1':'a value',
    'field2':'a value'
},
{
    '_id':'bar',
    'field1':'a value',
    'field2':'a value'
},
{
    '_id':'baz',
    'field1':'a value',
    'field3':'a value'
}
```

I'd like to know something like the following:

```
{
    'index':'goober',
    'field_counts':
        'field1':3,
        'field2':2,
        'field3':1
}
```

Is this doable with a single query?  or multiple?  For what it's worth, I'm using python [elasticsearch](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) and [elasticsearch-dsl](http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) clients.

I've successfully issued a `GET` request to `/goober` and retrieved the mappings, and am learning how to submit requests for aggregations for each field, but I'm interested in learning how many times a particular field appears across all documents.

Coming from using Solr, still getting my bearings with ES.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below will return you the count of docs with "field2":

```
POST /INDEX/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "field2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is an example using multiple aggregates (will return each agg in a bucket with a count), using field exist counts:

```
POST /INDEX/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "field_has1": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "field1"
        }
      }
    },
    "field_has2": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "field2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The behavior within each agg on the second example will mimic the behavior of the first query. In many cases, you can take a regular search query and nest those lookups within aggregate buckets.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks so much.

Comment: And if we want to count  : does not exists field1 , and does not exist field2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Quick time-saver based on existing answer:

```
interesting_fields = ['field1', 'field2']

body = {
    'size': 0,
    'aggs': {f'has_{field_name}': {
        "filter": {
            "exists": {
                "field": f'export.{field_name}'
            }
        }
    } for field_name in interesting_fields},
}

print(requests.post('http://localhost:9200/INDEX/_search', json=body).json())
```